# Import file in Odoo module

Tags: python, mysql, odoo

I am doing a module for Odoo that consists in importing csv, xls and xlsx files and those files are stored in a MySql database. The module should only consist in a field where you can find the file and treat it using a Python script.Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Comment: Why would you store the files in a MySql database when odoo uses psql? Second, storing files in a db is not a good idea, its slower than using the filestore and the odoo instance will work much slower too. for the other part, choosing and extracting the data from the file YES it is possible.

Comment: Thanks euroblaze for answer. I didn't restart the Odoo service and this gets me no results. I solved the problem ;)